# Pre-commit hook for devtools::document

Tags: r, git, githooks, devtools

I want to set-up a pre-commit hook for `devtools::document` and want to fail the commit if `devtools::document` changes anything. I checked the `devtools::document` source and it returns `invisible()` so it's not possible to conditionally return an exit code.

Are there any clever ways to stop the commit from happening when `devtools::document` does work?

Comment: `devtools::document()` writes a message to STDOUT (generally the console) whenever it changes a file: `Writing getScore.Rd`. Maybe if you can detect that, you could work with that.

Comment: Interesting, for me it also prints the updating and loading messages (in red), but they are not returned by `capture.output`.

Comment: Did you test that script yet? I have a feeling that that won't work. `capture.output` has two types of output to catch and with `message` you are only grabbing the two default messages (update and loading). The message `writing file.Rd` is not actually a message but rather output. **So you are not catching those right now.** You should change type to `type = "output"`, and then test for `length(lines) > 0`.

Comment: Did but messed up, some improvements made now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the function `capture.output` we can catch the messages `devtools::documents` sends whenever it changes a file:

```
Writing getScore.Rd
```

So when we run:

```
results <- capture.output(devtools::document())
```

When a document is updated (for this example, I removed one of my .Rd files, results looks as follows:

```
> results
[1] "Writing getScore.Rd"
```

If nothing is written, `results` is empty:

```
> results
character(0)
```

It is easy to go on from here I think :)

The OP, @BobJansen created the following script that runs the above method and returns a `status = 0` if no files were edited, and a `status = 100` if any where:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

source("packrat/init.R")

lines <- capture.output(devtools::document(), type = 'output')
if (length(lines) > 0) {
  print(lines)
  q(save = 'no', status = 100)
} else {
  q(save = 'no', status = 0)
}
```

Comment: Cleaned up my question

Answer (score 0):

There is a [hook](https://lorenzwalthert.github.io/precommit/articles/available-hooks.html#roxygenize-1) for `roxygen2::roxygenize()`, provided by the {precommit} package that works out of the box.

Disclosure: I am the maintainer.